# Jackson not populating all properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am working on a simple example using `Jackson library` to convert a `json` string back to `Java object` but I see only few properties are being set on my java object instead of all properties.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();       
        String data = "";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path-to-sample.json"));
            while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(data);
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close(); 
            }
        }

        System.out.println(buffer.toString());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Sample obj = mapper.readValue(buffer.toString(), Sample.class);


        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

The Sample.java program looks like this:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Sample {

    @JsonProperty("prop_1")
    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;
    @JsonProperty("prop_3")
    private String prop3;
    private String prop4;

    // Setters & Getters for the properties.

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sample [prop1=" + prop1 + ", prop2=" + prop2 + ", prop3="
                + prop3 + ", prop4=" + prop4 + "]";
    }

}
```

Input json string in my file is :

```
{
    "prop_1": "1",
    "prop2": "2",
    "prop_3": "3",
    "prop4": "4"
}
```

The output of this program is :

```
Sample [prop1=null, prop2=2, prop3=null, prop4=4]
```

As per my program the `prop1` and `prop3` should not be null. I am not clear where I made mistake.

**Update:**

If I remove the `@JsonProperty` annotation then I am getting the exception as :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "prop_1" (Class Sample), not marked as ignorable
```

This is my pom.xml file dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: which version of jackson you are using ?

Comment: That annotation works well with jersey/jackson which I prefer.

Comment: @SachinGupta, The version is `2.5.4`

Comment: @user2130951, I don't think Jackson is just limited to Jersey for its usage.

Comment: Try making the properties `public`. Alternatively try  `public void setProp_1(String prop1) { this.prop1 = prop1; }`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, Thanks for responding. Changing the fields to public has not fixed the issue. I have removed the `@JsonProperty` annotation and then changed the setter methods to `setProp_1` & `setProp_3`, it worked. So does it mean that there is an issue with `@JsonProperty`  annotation?

Comment: And if you keep `@JsonProperty("prop_1")` for your `private String prop1;` and just add `setProp1(...)` setter  ?

Comment: @boly38, my field is already having that annotation and I already have `setProp1` method. Please check the Sample.java code in my question.

Comment: sorry just miss the comment line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You said in your comment, that you're using Jackson in version *"2.5.4"*, but you're importing the `ObjectMapper` class from the `org.codehaus` package. This means, that this class is from version 1.9.13 (or from an older version).

I can reproduce your problem if I mix the versions using `ObjectMapper` and `JsonIgnoreProperties` from version 1.9.13 (`org.codehaus`) and `JsonProperty` from version 2.6.0 (`com.fasterxml`).

Output:

> Sample [prop1=null, prop2=2, prop3=null, prop4=4]

If I only use version 1.9.13 or 2.6.0, then the result is ok:

> Sample [prop1=1, prop2=2, prop3=3, prop4=4]

(for both)

So I recommend to make sure that you don't mix the used libraries and I recommend to use the newest version, which is from [FasterXML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).
But the used version is up to you.

You can download the jar file from here:

- [org.codehaus.jackson v1.9.13](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson)
- [com.fasterxml.jackson (core) v2.6.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core)

Btw about your comment:

> @OldCurmudgeon, Thanks for responding. Changing the fields to public has not fixed the issue. I have removed the @JsonProperty annotation and then changed the setter methods to setProp_1 & setProp_3, it worked. So does it mean that there is an issue with @JsonProperty annotation?

Yes, you have (or hopefully had :P) a problem with that annotation: it was from a different Jackson version.

About your edit:

The link to the Jackson lib from fasterXML in the maven repository has one big advantage: it shows you which lib you should download to work with Jackson in your project.

You need:

- [Jackson Databind](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind) (which also has the `ObjectMapper` class)
- [Jackson Core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core)
- [Jackson Annotations](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations)

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot Tom, the issue is solved now. Correct I mixed the annotations for `JsonIgnoreProperties` and `JsonProperty` with codehaus and Jackson. Can you please tell me what is the correct way to use, should I use Jackson jars or codehaus jars?

Comment: Well, first of all: both are "Jackson" :P, but codehaus is an older version which will not be maintained anymore. So, you should use the newer version from fasterXML. You can find the recent versions here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core (link is also in the answer).

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but I don't see any `ObjectMapper` in Jackson jars. I am trying to import the class file for `ObjectMapper`, i am getting from codehaus only. I have updated my question with the dependencies in my pom.xml file, can you please check and suggest.

Comment: That class is in the "Jackson Databind" lib. I've added that info to the answer.

Comment: A good replacement for the big dependency is. <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>