# submitting json data through ajax call not working in spring controller

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs, spring, model-view-controller

I have an angularjs page, from which I am trying to pass inputs as JSON object to spring controller through ajax call and trying to assign it to a user defined class to save it. But all the values comes as `null` in the user object. Below is my code.

Controller method code(POST request):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value ={"/addEvent"})
    @ResponseBody
    public void addEvent(@RequestBody final EventsMstr eventsMstr) {
        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@   addEvent controller started.");
        System.out.println("eventsMstr = " + eventsMstr);//Prints null for all the fields
        this.eventsMstrService.addEvent(new EventsMstr());
    }
```

Ajax call:

```
SaveEvent: function (param) {
                 var successCallback = null;
                 var errorCallback = null;
                 alert("Param "+param.EventTypeId + param.StartDate+param.EndDate+param.Description);//values getting printed
                 $http({
                     url: config.InsertEvent,
                     type: "POST",
                     data: JSON.stringify(param),
                     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
                 })
                .success(function (data, httpStatus, headers) {
                    successCallback(data, httpStatus, headers);
                })
                .error(function (httpStatus, headers) {
                    successCallback(data, httpStatus, headers);
                });
                 return {
                     success: function (callback) {
                         successCallback = callback;
                         return {
                             error: function (callback) {
                                 errorCallback = callback;
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
             },
```

I have annotated all the fields of my class with `@JsonProperty`. I am not sure whether I am missing something here. Suggestions greatly appreciated.

Spring servlet configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="jsonConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
         <value>application/json</value>
         <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8</value>
        </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

JSON data:

```
var EventItem = {
            EventTypeId: $scope.eventTypeId,
            StartDate: $scope.startDate,
            EndDate: $scope.EndDate,
            Description: $scope.EventName
        };
```

Bean class:

```
package com.ems.business.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

//import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;


@XmlRootElement(name = "EventsMaster")
//@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EventsMstr implements java.io.Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private Long eventTypeId;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private String description;

    public EventsMstr() {
    }
        public EventsMstr(Long id, Long eventTypeId, Date startDate, Date endDate,
            String description) {

        this.id = id;
        this.eventTypeId = eventTypeId;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("EventTypeId")
    public Long getEventTypeId() {
        return eventTypeId;
    }

    public void setEventTypeId(Long eventTypeId) {
        this.eventTypeId = eventTypeId;
    }

    @JsonProperty("StartDate")
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    @JsonProperty("EndDate")
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EventsMstr [id=" + id + ", startDate=" + startDate
                + ", endDate=" + endDate + ", description=" + description
                + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: post your bean class code please

Comment: make sure [you're not using an old version ObjectMapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560530/jackson-not-populating-all-properties). Please post your `pom.xml`

Comment: Why are you setting the header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?  Should that be application/json?

Comment: @Anand Previously I was using `@JsonIgnoreProperties` and `@JsonProperty` from `org.codehaus.jackson.mapper.1.4.2`, now I changed it to `jackson-annotations-2.2.1`. But I am getting MappingException now. As you can see I have mapped all the properties correctly. Below is the exception:
`org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized field "EventTypeId" (Class com.ems.business.model.EventsMstr), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1a33ad7; line: 1, column: 2]`

Comment: @anand I am not using Maven

Comment: @GreenMan If I change the `Content-Type` to `application/json`, the request is not going into the controller. But I am sure that the JS function is calling the controller method URL, as I can see some comments printed from filter class

Comment: First we'll try to figure out the fields that are not getting mapped. Try to include these lines and run it. `ObjectMapper mapper = 
      new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`

Comment: Then you probably need to set the "consumes" on the RequestMapping to consume JSON too.

Answer (score 0):

It was my carelessness which ate my two days. What I did wrong is, instead of annotating the properties, I was annotating the getter methods. Below is the modified object class.

```
package com.ems.business.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

//import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;


@XmlRootElement(name = "EventsMaster")
//@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class EventsMstr implements java.io.Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonProperty("ID")
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty("EventTypeId")
    private Long eventTypeId;
    @JsonProperty("StartDate")
    private Date startDate;
    @JsonProperty("EndDate")
    private Date endDate;
    @JsonProperty("Description")
    private String description;

    public EventsMstr() {
    }
        public EventsMstr(Long id, Long eventTypeId, Date startDate, Date endDate,
            String description) {

        this.id = id;
        this.eventTypeId = eventTypeId;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getEventTypeId() {
        return eventTypeId;
    }

    public void setEventTypeId(Long eventTypeId) {
        this.eventTypeId = eventTypeId;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EventsMstr [id=" + id + ", startDate=" + startDate
                + ", endDate=" + endDate + ", description=" + description
                + "]";
    }
}
```

Also the request mapping should be like below:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value ={"/addEvent"}, 
            headers = {"content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"})
    public @ResponseBody EventsMstr addEvent(@RequestBody EventsMstr eventsMstr) {
        this.eventsMstrService.addEvent(eventsMstr);
        return eventsMstr;
    }
```