# Jackson UnrecognizedPropertyException

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am trying to convert JsonString to Java object.

Json object

```
{
"action": "added",
"data": {
    "Quote": {
        "TotalDiscountsAmount": 0,
        "Id": "test123"
    },
    "Owner": {
        "Username": "00000000",
        "Id": "00000000"
    },
    "Discount_Amount__c": 0,
    "Base_List_Price__c": 574.88,
    "TotalList": 574.88,
    "Id": "000000",
    "ExtendedTotalList": 574.88,
    "BaseListPrice": 474.88
}
}
```

My POJOs:

**AddtocartJson.java**

```
package com.product.json;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  "action",
  "data"
})
public class AddToCartJson {
    @JsonProperty("action")
    private String action;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Data data;

    @JsonProperty("action")
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    @JsonProperty("action")
    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**Data.java**

```
package com.product.json;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  "Quote",
  "Owner",
  "Discount_Amount__c",
  "Base_List_Price__c",
  "TotalList",
  "Id",
  "ExtendedTotalList",
  "BaseListPrice"
})
public class Data {

    @JsonProperty("Quote")
    private com.product.json.Quote Quote;
    @JsonProperty("Owner")
    private com.product.json.Owner Owner;
    @JsonProperty("Discount_Amount__c")
    private Integer DiscountAmountC;
    @JsonProperty("Base_List_Price__c")
    private Double BaseListPriceC;
    @JsonProperty("TotalList")
    private Double TotalList;
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    private String Id;
    @JsonProperty("ExtendedTotalList")
    private Double ExtendedTotalList;
    @JsonProperty("BaseListPrice")
    private Double BaseListPrice;

    @JsonProperty("Quote")
    public com.product.json.Quote getQuote() {
        return Quote;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Quote")
    public void setQuote(com.product.json.Quote Quote) {
        this.Quote = Quote;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Owner")
    public com.product.json.Owner getOwner() {
        return Owner;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Owner")
    public void setOwner(com.product.json.Owner Owner) {
        this.Owner = Owner;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Discount_Amount__c")
    public Integer getDiscountAmountC() {
        return DiscountAmountC;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Discount_Amount__c")
    public void setDiscountAmountC(Integer DiscountAmountC) {
        this.DiscountAmountC = DiscountAmountC;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Base_List_Price__c")
    public Double getBaseListPriceC() {
        return BaseListPriceC;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Base_List_Price__c")
    public void setBaseListPriceC(Double BaseListPriceC) {
        this.BaseListPriceC = BaseListPriceC;
    }

    @JsonProperty("TotalList")
    public Double getTotalList() {
        return TotalList;
    }

    @JsonProperty("TotalList")
    public void setTotalList(Double TotalList) {
        this.TotalList = TotalList;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ExtendedTotalList")
    public Double getExtendedTotalList() {
        return ExtendedTotalList;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ExtendedTotalList")
    public void setExtendedTotalList(Double ExtendedTotalList) {
        this.ExtendedTotalList = ExtendedTotalList;
    }

    @JsonProperty("BaseListPrice")
    public Double getBaseListPrice() {
        return BaseListPrice;
    }

    @JsonProperty("BaseListPrice")
    public void setBaseListPrice(Double BaseListPrice) {
        this.BaseListPrice = BaseListPrice;
    }
}
```

**Quote.java**

```
package com.product.json;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  "TotalDiscountsAmount",
  "Id"
})
public class Quote {
    @JsonProperty("TotalDiscountsAmount")
    private Integer TotalDiscountsAmount;
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    private String Id;

    @JsonProperty("TotalDiscountsAmount")
    public Integer getTotalDiscountsAmount() {
        return TotalDiscountsAmount;
    }

    @JsonProperty("TotalDiscountsAmount")
    public void setTotalDiscountsAmount(Integer TotalDiscountsAmount) {
        this.TotalDiscountsAmount = TotalDiscountsAmount;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }
}
```

When I try to convert JSON to Java class using the mapper, it's throwing an `UnrecognizedPropertyException`. Seems likes even though I have a `Quote` object somehow mapper is not able to recognize the object.

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Quote" (Class com.product.json.Data), not marked as ignorable
>       at [Source: java.io.StringReader@11547748; line: 1, column: 36] (through reference chain: com.product.json.AddToCartJson["data"]->       com.product.json.Data["Quote"])
>           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
>           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
>           at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you try changing your import to _org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.*_ for annotations?

Comment: and also use the latest version of jackson

Comment: @Sam, thanks and can you add your comment as an Answer.So that I can accept the answer

Comment: This problem here is similar to the problem in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560530/jackson-not-populating-all-properties/31569994

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that OP mixes two different Jackson versions:

- 1.9 from `org.codehaus` (`org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException` shows that)
- 2.x from `com.fasterxml` (visible in the imports `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.`)

As pointed out by [sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1720938/sam) in the comments, OP should only use one version. Either use 2.x for deserialization or use annotations from the old 1.9 version.
But it is recommended to use the newest version from `com.fasterxml`, instead of the old one.

Comment: I had the same issue thanks to IJs crappy auto import thanks!

Comment: @Jackie Well, the IDE can only import stuff that's already in the classpath, so the question is: why do you have two different versions in the classpath?  :)

Comment: fair enough but buried somewhere as the dependency of some outdated dependency isn't the easiest to mitigate.

Answer (score 5):

you might want to ignore undefined properties by using Jackson's class-level annotation:

@JsonIgnoreProperties